# What causes Bootstrap to show alternate versions of glyphicons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to render a gylphicon via below code, but a different glyphicon from what I'd normally expect is being rendered in the view.

```
<span class="gyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
```

**Expected icon**

[image]

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

**Actual icon rendered**

[image]

Bootstrap 3.3.6 is currently installed via ruby gem.

**Note: I looked at glyphicons from previous versions of Bootstrap and it doesn't actually appear to be from an old version**

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Comment: did you check the font file you downloaded is latest...?

Comment: Front file version means like `bootstrap 3.3.6`?

Comment: yes bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\fonts\

Comment: Per `gem list` i see `3.3.6` is the version installed.

Comment: can we see the code..?